# Twitter Api Not Allowing Correct Access

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm attempting to use the Twitter api via `Twifer` in PHP in order to authenticate users and post tweets with media attached automatically. I understand that the only way you can post media is through the V1.1 endpoints, requiring elevated access.

I applied and got granted this access see in developer portal, seeing `Elevated`, `V1.1 Access` and `V2 access`, so theres no doubt that this is enabled. I am able to authenticate a user with my callback url and post a regular tweet with this.

```
$conn = new API($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token['oauth_token'], 
$access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$postfields = '{"text":"Tweet test for php"}';
$res = $conn->request('POST', '/2/tweets', $postfields);
```

**However...**
When attempting to use the V1.1 endpoint for something as simple as

```
$user = $conn->request("GET", "account/verify_credentials");
```

I see `You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal.`
I have attempted to regenerate all keys and can confirm I have read and write permissions under my app permissions section of the developer portal for this project.

Could this be an issue of running locally via `http://dev.user.domain.co.uk` which I doubt due to being able to post using the V2 api.

Comment: I also get this error using another library, Twit.  What's weird, is it works for one app/user and it doesn't for another and there is no difference.  I have regenerated and recreated the project/app multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new developer account.

I had Twitter Developers account for a few years. Few days ago, my app is suspended and can't login via Twitter on my website. I applied migration to new aceess tier but still pengin over 10 days.

So I've created new developer account today.
I can't find `v1.1 Access` `v2.0 Access`, `elevated` on my new project & app.
But `account/verify_credentials` API works well with `include_email` option.